# Fullscreen mode in spotify app

Tags: fullscreen, spotify

I want to create a party mode app for spotify. Ideally I would like to launch my app in fullscreen - is this possible? I can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, fullscreen mode is not supported in the Spotify Apps at the moment.